# Passing a graph (list of lists) as parameter by reference, I want to add elements to each list to be used inside this function only

Tags: c++, graph

I have a function which receives a directed graph represented as a list of lists that needs to do this:

```
int Algo::test(const vector<vector<int> > &graph) {
    ...
    // Add a few edges to the graph
    // Do calculations based on the graph
}
```

I may or may not use `const`.

For this function to work, I need to add a few other edges to the graph (need to make sure there is a [w,v] for every edge [v,w]). I'll never remove anything, just add, and I will not reorder the edges, so every new edge should be appended at the end of its respective list. At the end of this function, the graph should be left in its initial state.

I thought of two obvious ways to do this:

(1) Use `const` and copy the graph:

```
vector<vector<int> > graph2(graph);
// Work on graph2
```

(2) Do not use `const`, save the current size of each list in the original graph, modify it and in the end erase the added elements:

```
vector<unsigned> origSizes(graph.size());
for (unsigned i = 0; i < graph.size(); i++) 
    origSizes[i] = graph[i].size();

// Create edges and do calculations

for (unsigned i = 0; i < graph.size(); i++) 
    graph[i].erase(graph[i].begin() + origSizes[i], graph[i].end();
```

I don't like solution (1) because copying the entire graph seems like too much overhead to me (the graph may be large). I don't like solution (2)  because I would prefer to use `const` and not modify the original graph internally.

Is there any other alternative way that is more efficient and/or safer than these two options?

Comment: Why would you use const if the function need to modify the graph? Does it need the modified version internally or should it modify the graph when it returns?

Comment: You're using vector of vector, not list, there're different inside

Comment: You say list but use vector. Which is it? (Yes I know you were speaking conceptually, not in C++ terms. No that doesn't change my comment)

Comment: List in computer science terminology, vector in C++. That should be clear from context.

And the modified version is used only internally, not outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can augment the graph using your own data structure:

```
int Algo::test(const vector<vector<int> > &graph) {
    vector<vector<int> > extra_edges(graph.size());
    // Add the edges to extra_edges
    // Do stuff using both extra_edges and graph
    ...
}
```

Add the edges you need to `extra_edges`.  When you actually do your computation, be sure to check *both* the original edges and also the ones you've added yourself via `extra_edges`.

The downside is that it makes the code a bit more complicated, however, but this is the least intrusive approach besides copying everything.

Comment: Why would you initialize `extra_edges` to be of equal length (capacity) of the input graph?

Comment: Thanks Rufflewind, that indeed adds complexity to the code, but seems to be the best way so far. I may end up doing this, wanted to avoid as I keep some extra data structures to speed up my algorithm, and this may actually complicate the code quite a lot. But I haven't given any details of my algorithm, so... might end up doing it.

Comment: @haavee I'm assuming an adjacency list representation here.